# Keep track of which CheckBox has been Checked

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, forms

I've a list of checkboxes populated from a JSON get query. I need to keep track of all the checkboxes that have been checked.
Moreover I need to convert the checked Checkboxes into JSON format after the submit button has been clicked.

My JSON looks something like this:

```
[
{
  permissionName: "permission1",
  permissionId: "1",
},
{
  permissionName: "permission2",
  permissionId: "2",
}
]
```

I have checkboxes which contain various permissions with permissionName as label. I need to keep track of all the checkboxes checked.

```
export default class Permissions extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            schemas: [],
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
        PermissionsApi.getAllPermissionList()
            .then(
            result => {

                this.setState({ schemas: result});
                console.log(result);
            },
            error => {
                this.handleError(error);
            }
            )
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App">
              {this.state.schemas.map((permissions, permissionId) => {
                  return(
                      <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="{permissions.permissionName}" value="{permissions.permissionId}"/>
                            <label>
                                {permissions.permissionName}
                            </label>
                      </div>
                  )
              })}
              <button>Convert Into JSON when this button is clicked.</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tracking the checkboxes checked status and creating the json after you clicked the button, you can just create a state that will store all checked items as json and once you click the button, simply submit that checked json whenever you want.

You just need to remove the object from the checked array when the user unchecked the box.

Here's the code for that, read the comments in code for explanation

```
export class Permissions extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      schemas: [],
      checked: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
    PermissionsApi.getAllPermissionList()
      .then(
        result => {
          this.setState({ schemas: result });
        },
        error => {
          this.handleError(error);
        }
      )
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  //this will handle the check action to your checkboxes
  handleCheck(permission) {
    const { permissionId } = permission;

    //store your checked state in a temporary variable so we can mutate it
    const tempchecked = this.state.checked;

    //check if the object already exist in the checked array
    if (this.state.checked.find(item => item.permissionId === permissionId)) {
      //if already exist, it means the action is uncheck, thus remove
      tempchecked.splice(tempchecked.indexOf(permission), 1);
    } else {
      //if didnt exist, it means the action is check, thus add
      tempchecked.push(permission);
    }

    console.log(tempchecked);

    //set checked state
    this.setState({ checked: tempchecked });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.schemas.map((permissions, permissionId) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="{permissions.permissionName}"
                value="{permissions.permissionId}"
                onChange={() => this.handleCheck(permissions)}
              />
              <label>{permissions.permissionName}</label>
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <br />
        <button>Convert Into JSON when this button is clicked.</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can playaround with the working sandbox of that code I've posted [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-snyder-q01ix)

Comment: Thanks a-lot. This is working perfectly.
Moreover thanks for adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular and I do not have experience with Reactjs. However I think it might be possible to bind a `click` event to the checkbox, so that you can update your model once it is clicked (since as far as I know, React is unidirectional and not 2-way binding).

Something like:

```
    return (
        <div className="App">
          {this.state.schemas.map((permissions, permissionId) => {
              return(
                  <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{permissions.permissionName}" value="{permissions.permissionId}" (click)="setChecked(permissionId)"/>
                        <label>
                            {permissions.permissionName}
                        </label>
                  </div>
              )
```

And in your method `setChecked(permissionId)` you might add the selected permission/entity to a "selected" array (note that you have to remove the entry from there if the checkbox will then be de-selected). 

Alternatively you can extend your permission model with a further property "selected" that is set to true when the checkbox is clicked.

Either approach you chose, when the submit button is clicked, you can iterate over your array (if 1. approach) or the `selected = true` permissions (if 2. approach).

I am sorry i cannot provide you the right Reactjs syntax, but I hope this suggestions will lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another state object to maitain the checked state of the permissions.

Here is how you add that state

```
this.state = {
      schemas: [],
      checkedPermissions: []
    }
```

and here is how you can maitain that state

```
  CheckPermissions(permissionID) {
    const isChecked = this.state.checkedPermissions.some(a => a === permissionID);
    if (isChecked) {
      this.setState({ checkedPermissions: this.state.checkedPermissions.filter(a => a !== permissionID) })
    } else {
      const data = this.state.checkedPermissions;
      data.push(permissionID);
      this.setState({ checkedPermissions: data });
    }

  }
```

check out demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4tkdkc)